# Why is onCreate overridden?

Tags: java, android

I have a question about Androids onCreate method. I understand that the Activity is extended and that `onCreate()` is implemented as android developers guide states (Class Overview at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). But why do we use `@Override`? And also if i want to refer to that method what word should i use? Should i say that `onCreate() is Overrided` or that `onCreate() is implemented` ?

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }
```

Comment: It's "overridden" (you were close in your title, but it has two r's), not "overrided".

Comment: It's just an **annotation**, that just tells that the method written below is overridden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onCreate` is "Overridden" because Activity has an existing implementation that your class `MainActivity` is replacing with it's own implementation. you would say "implemented" if the method is only declared in an interface, but there is no implementation in a super class your are replacing.

the annotation `@Override` is an optional (but recommanded) hint for the compiler that the following method signature must exists in the super class or interface your are extending. It will result in an compile error if this is not the case. It's also a hint for the developer that this method also exists in the super class.

Answer (score 1):

`@Override` is an annotation that will throw a **compilation error** if the signatures of the methods don't match (for example if you omit the parameter savedInstanceState) and that's how an overridden method is marked.

Furthermore the method is not implemented because it already has an implementation in `Activity` (which is called by super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) ) it is **overridden**

Did I answer your question?

Comment: thanks but the above person answered it sooner :(

Answer (score 0):

you have to override that Method because it isn't directly implemented in the superclass. You can say 'It's overridden'.